# Unintentionally proven false theorem with type-in-type outside logic and foundations?

Tags: foundations, history, predicativity, universe, consistency

We are all familiar with Russell's paradox, and [it is known](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/1220) that Per Martin-Löf proved that type-in-type is normalizing and consistent (which is false), by accidentally using an assumption in his meta-theory that is essentially type-in-type. But all these arise in the areas of logic and foundations. Has anyone proven some statement Q by accidentally using some type-in-type assumption, without being aware that such an assumption is unsound, and such that Q can be shown to be surely false (say in a typical predicative type theory)?

The linked example would be considered to be under foundations. Here is another example that is not quite under logic or foundations but anyone who proves it will certainly be immediately aware that the type-in-type assumption is unsound: Let W be the type of all rooted (downward-directed) trees with no infinite (downward) path. Let T be a rooted tree whose root has exactly the members of W as children. Now T is in W...

So is there any example where the person who proved the result was still unaware (at least for a reasonable period of time) that the type-in-type assumption was unsound?

Comment: I seem to remember some discussion about accidental universe inconsistencies that were masked at first. Maybe Mike Shulman communicated them, I'll try to remember.

Comment: @AndrejBauer is this the one: https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/1219/has-anyone-ever-accidentally-proven-a-false-theorem-with-type-in-type ? I don't know if this fits the question, though: I would say it is outside of logic and foundation, but Mike Shulman says he does not know whether it holds or not, so it probably cannot "be shown to be surely false" with our current knowledge…

Comment: Yes, that's the one I was thinking of!

Comment: Just about anyone who learns type theory nowadays knows about type-in-type. So if there is an example of what you're asking for, it would have to have taken place in the narrow period between Martin-Löf's type theory with type-in-type, and the realization that it's inconsistent.

Comment: Or in the glory era of early Unimath, when they decided to use type-in-type to avoid issues with universes? Which looks like the time to which Mike Shulman's example belongs.

Comment: @MevenLennon-Bertrand: But did that result in any false theorem that was believed to be a good theorem?

Comment: @AndrejBauer: It need not be in type theory. Naive set theory also has a type-in-type assumption, even if it is not called "type". I'm not intending to restrict answers to only type theories of a particular narrow tradition.

Comment: I don't count Mike's example by the way, as it is literally about type theories, which is squarely in logic and foundations. After all, I did link to that thread in my question!

Comment: Mike's example looks like it's "just" about type theory, but it actually has a much wider applicability.

Comment: @AndrejBauer: Let me put it another way; if an example was actually utilized to obtain a theorem in the language of higher-order arithmetic that is believed to be incorrect, then I would agree that that obtained theorem is an actual example of the type I am looking for. If not, then I'm unlikely to buy that it is outside of logic and foundations.

Comment: I vaguely remember Benabou, or perhaps Dobus, telling some cautionary tales about faulty reasoning in category theory, where mistakes can be made easily enough if one does not pay attention to class-set distinction. But I don't know the reference.

Comment: @AndrejBauer: I vaguely recall reading some examples of that sort, yes, but to me those are due to wishful thinking way beyond higher-order arithmetic. Ultimately, what is the difference between those mistakes and Frege's Axiom V? The point is that a lot of these explorations were based on dubious axioms that arose out of logic and foundations, and were not things that mathematicians genuinely believed to be true in a platonic sense.

Comment: Still running on vague memories, I think one of the pertinent observations was that “$f : A \to B$ is epi” in a large category involves universal quantification over a class. Speaking type-theoretically, the type of epis in a category $C$ living in a universe $U$ might live outside $U$. So for instance, if we take the subcategory of epis in $C$, we've bumped up the universes. But ultimately, we'd have to find the specific objections to see in what way they're problematic.

Comment: @AndrejBauer: Yes, but that has nothing to do with category theory; it is just plain foundational concerns, because it just comes down to saying that sets are closed under function types but classes are not (if you only have two levels). In turn, this is ultimately like Frege's Axiom V; because it is just another result of 'wishful thinking' that certain concepts have reifications.  If people want to reason about any 'large' things without giving solid justification why those things can even be reified in the first place, then it's just like asking for Russel's paradox all over again.

Comment: And negation is not even needed, nor is any notion at all about 'categories'. To see why, if type∈type, then let S be the 'type' of all types x such that ∀t∈{ 0 : x∈x } ( ⊥ ), and it is trivial to obtain ⊥ by constructive proof: Given any t∈{ 0 : S∈S }, we have S∈S and so ∀t∈{ 0 : S∈S } ( ⊥ ), hence ⊥. Therefore S∈S, and so ⊥. By the way, if we require a type's defining predicate to quantify over only predicative types, then we **can** have type∈type in a predicative system!